# jadclipse Error during DECOMPILATION REPORT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jad

I am using Eclipse Helios Version and imported an existing project into IDE.

This Project is consisting some code in form of Jar files

So I have installed Jad Eclipse plugin .

Now my question is from the IDE  Whenever i click class (Ctrl + Mouse) which is in jar files , instead of java file ,i m getting this

```
/*jadclipse*/

/*
    DECOMPILATION REPORT

    Decompiled from: C:\Documents and Settings\Sai\Desktop\work\kiuybon-1.1.jar
    Total time: 0 ms
    Jad reported messages/errors:
    Exit status: 0
    Caught exceptions:
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "jad" (in directory "C:\Documents and Settings\Sai\.net.sf.jadclipse\1321168101468"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.jadclipse.JadDecompiler.decompile(JadDecompiler.java:160)
    at net.sf.jadclipse.JadDecompiler.decompileFromArchive(JadDecompiler.java:217)
    at
```

Answer (score 4):

Go to `Preference --> Java --> Jadclipse`

Set the path to decompiler to the location of your jad.exe and point the temp file directory to something like `c:\temp` (make sure you create this directory)

Comment: Didn't work for me. It adds a directory with a bunch of numbers and says it can't reach it. When I create that directory in the FS it shows the same message. If I restart eclipse it picks a new numbers directory. I also tried adding my name to the jad.exe.

Answer (score 0):

You can make "C:\Documents and Settings\Sai.net.sf.jadclipse\1321168101468" directory to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Even I have also faced the same problem. You can use an alternative de-compiler mentioned below. It works perfect in eclipse

http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the archive with jad.exe from http://varaneckas.com/jad/ for your OS
2. Extract in a specific folder
3. Go to Window > Preferences > Java > JadClipse and fill the path to decompile with the path where you extracted the archive
4. Restart your eclipse.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ry6l.png)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error: **jadclipse**

```
 DECOMPILATION REPORT
 Decompiled from: D:\nnn\nnnn\lib\nnn3.1.1.jar
 Total time: 0 ms
 Jad reported messages/errors:
 Exit status: 0
 Caught exceptions:
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "c:\jad" (in directory "C:\jad\1490924748657"): 
         CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
```

To solve it I did the following steps:

1. Added my windows profile as the owner of the jad.exe. I was already admin on my machine but doing only this did not solve the problem.

   jad.exe > right click > Properties > security > advanced > owner tab >
   change owner to > my windows profile
2. Restart eclipse. Tried debugging again and the problem is solved.